# Fail2ban add more info to email notificationd

Tags: fail2ban

I'd like to append the relevant fail2ban log entry to the notification email I already receive for any given incident.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what information you would like - you may edit the appropriate `action.d` configuration file's `actionban` segment by copying the `.conf` version to a `.local` version which will override the `.conf` version [as per the fail2ban documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Configuration), and edit it to include whatever information you would like. For example, I have personally amended my `sendmail-whois.conf` (which is the main sendmail action I use - you could do likewise with sendmail.conf however if you use that for example) by copying it to `sendmail-whois.local` which I then edited to include the server hostname on the '`From:`' line.

You could also include commands to be executed with their output passed to the email to be sent, as long as you follow the correct syntax and fully qualify the path to the relevant commands - for example, you will see that the `sendmail-whois` action configuration contains the line, within the `actionban` segment;

```html
`/usr/bin/whois <ip>`\n
```

Note, as I have mentioned above - the full path to the relevant command is included (in this case, for `whois`), and the entire command with its options must be delimited by backquotes. the `\n` at the end of the line indicates that a new line be printed following this one in the output.

Hope that clarifies things for you!